# How to keep my apps data undelete even if my app is removed?

Tags: ios, swift

My app is a Gov app where a user captures photo and record some notes about it.

When the user removed the app, all data are lost.

Is there a place where I can store data (notes & photos) for the user even if they removed my app, then installed it again, it will be still there?

Note: This can be done easily with Android, by using a public directory.

Comment: Use a server and sync the data. There is no way to keep the image and other data on phone even after it's removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use server to save large files.
and keep user **token** in keychain. The data in **keychain** will **NOT** be deleted when app was deleted.

when user reinstall your app, you can get this **token**, and use it to download large files.

**iCloud** is other space to save your data.